# How to display wp-content file system in a front end page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a download page on my WordPress website, I have created folders that link to a download file in my wp-content/downloads.
What I would like to achieve is instead of the folder I created, I would like to have the file system "wp-content/download" displayed as it is on my frontend page.
The file system should display other folders and files, and allow users to download.
Kindly assist on how to go about this issue. a plugin suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Something based on [scandir](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.scandir.php) would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily. In wordpress there is a neat function

```
<?php $url = content_url(); ?>
```

you can get that downloads folder easily from these

Happy Coding